# Dynamically changing the introspect endpoint URL based on HTTP request params

Tags: http, url, oauth-2.0, service, ballerina

I have a REST API secured with an OAuth2 bearer token in Ballerina. The current configuration looks like this:

```
@http:ServiceConfig {
    cors: {
        allowOrigins: [config:CORS_ORIGIN],
        maxAge: 84900
    },
    auth: [
        {
            oauth2IntrospectionConfig: {
                url: config:INTROSPECT_EP_URL,
                tokenTypeHint: "access_token",
                clientConfig: {
                    customHeaders: {"Authorization": "Basic " + base64EncodedHeader},
                    secureSocket: {
                        disable: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a requirement to change the introspect URL based on the HTTPS request parameters. I have 2 different IDPs and need to call the respective introspection endpoint based on the HTTP request. Is there a way to change the `url:`  param dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can use the imperative approach using a map of `http:ListenerOAuth2Handler` instances. The key for this map would be the relevant request parameter, and the corresponding value would be an `http:ListenerOAuth2Handler`. You can follow the OAuth2 spec for more details [here](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerina-oauth2/blob/master/docs/spec/spec.md#512-imperative-approach-http-listener).

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```php
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/oauth2;

service /yourEndpoint on securedListenerEp {
    resource function post yourResource(@http:Header string authorization, string oauth2ReqParam) returns string|http:Unauthorized|http:Forbidden {
        oauth2:IntrospectionResponse|http:Unauthorized|http:Forbidden auth = authorize(oauth2ReqParam, authorization, "admin");
        if auth is http:Unauthorized || auth is http:Forbidden {
            return auth;
        }
        // Your business logic here
    }
}

map<http:ListenerOAuth2Handler> oauth2Handlers = {
    // Populate this map with your listener-oauth2 handlers
};

function authorize(string oauth2ReqParam, string authorizationHeader, string... scopes) returns oauth2:IntrospectionResponse|http:Unauthorized|http:Forbidden {
    if !oauth2Handlers.hasKey(oauth2ReqParam) {
        return http:UNAUTHORIZED;
    }
    http:ListenerOAuth2Handler oauth2Handler = oauth2Handlers.get(oauth2ReqParam);
    return oauth2Handler->authorize(authorizationHeader, scopes);
}
```